# PHPSpec loads file but not directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

This commands works (specify file):

```
./vendor/bin/phpspec.php Spec/Model/Entity/DescribeCustomer.php -f d -c --bootstrap module/Application/tests/Bootstrap.php
```

But using the directory does not:

```
./vendor/bin/phpspec.php Spec/ -f d -c --bootstrap module/Application/tests/Bootstrap.php
```

Composer file

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec": "*"
}
```

Version

```
./vendor/bin/phpspec.php --version 
1.4.2
```

Comment: composer "require-dev": {
   "phpspec/phpspec": "*"
}

Comment: have you tried to update to 2nd version of phpspec? :)